# IF function Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to sum values from 3 different columns when there is a change in the values

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GFi2.jpg)

I came up with this IF formulas :

```
=IF(AND((B2-A2)=0,(C2-B2)=0),0, SUM(B2:C2))
```

The formulas work when the value of `(C2-B2) > 0`
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWYRy.jpg)
However, it doesn't take into account the change when `(B2-A2)> 0`[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDSS0.jpg)
what argument should I add for my formula ? thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=IF(AND((B2-A2)=0,(C2-B2)=0),0, SUM(A2:C2))
```

The `AND()` will be true only if all three values are the same; if false, then sum the three values.

**NOTE:**

```
SUM(A2:C2)
```

is the same as:

```
A2 + B2 + C2
```

if there are numerical values in all three cells.

Comment: Actually i want it to `SUM A2:B2` when `B2-A2 > 0` and `C2:B2` when `C2-B2 > 0` and `A2:C2 `when `B2-A2 > 0 and C2-B2 >0` and return 0 when `(B2-A2)=0,(C2-B2)=0`

Comment: @sarah `=IF(AND((B2-A2)>0,(C2-B2)>0),SUM(A2:C2),IF((B2-A2)>0,SUM(A2:B2),IF((C2-B2)>0,SUM(B2:C2),"")))`

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes !! thank you !!